# InvocationTargetException and a coding discussion

Tags: android

This code is throwing a invocationTargetException. 
There are a few problems with this code:

1. It is still entering the if statement even though I specifically told it not too when nothing is input into the `EditText`.
2. I am guessing the exception could have occurred because of the `parseInt` not having anything to parse (Although that shouldn't be a problem).
3. A cause of this type exception should be not initiating something at the right time, should it not?

   ```
   if(ageText.getText().toString() != "" || ageText.getText().toString() != null)
   {
       newCharacterController.characterAge = Integer.parseInt(ageText.getText().toString());
   }
   ```

A little off topic too, I cant seem to find the `tag` of any of the containers like a `Spinner` or `EditText`, when I look into the `mTag` value of it when the program is running, will this affect my `if(parent.getTag() == "OBJECTIDGIVENBYMYSELF")` and stop if from working? Also is there a better way to gain the `tag` value (.getType() in C#).

An example of the above OBJECTNAMEGIVENBYMYSELF is `EditText ***newEditText*** = new EditText(this);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ageText.getText().toString() != ""
```

The above code is not a good practice to compare String content, simply because comparison operator such as "==" is used to compare by reference but not value. I think you should use the following code instead

```
ageText.getText().toString().equals("")
```

And by the way, check null before this.

Comment: What do you mean "check null". I will give that a go right now thanks.

Comment: `ageText.getText().toString() != null` should be done before checking empty String. This is a common practice in condition checking. However, in Android, `EditText.getText().toString()` should never be null, so you may simply skip the null pointer checking.